# Xamarin.Android Internet Permission

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, min sdk version 14.
I have read everywhere that after building a release version you need to specify internet permssions in the manifest. (although some people say that it's only neccessary if your a building for android version below x version).

This is a extract of my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="<app name>" android:icon="@drawable/icon"></application>
```

The thing is that when building and running straight from Visual to my device, I can't access internet from my app.

In the device's application manager I can see that the permissions assigned to my app are the following (wether it's deployed from visual studio or installed from Google Play):
 **- Modify or delete the contents of your USB storage**
 **- Full Network access**
 **- View Network Connections**

On the other hand, when uploading the app to Goolge Play (alpha test), when I click install in my phone, the popup that shows the permissions that the app is going to use, shows it needs is "Access to Photos/Media/Files"

[EDIT]
The way my app is accessing internet is through a PCL Project.
Basically this is the chunk of code that does (or does not) all the magic.

```
        try
        {
            if (CheckIfThereIsConnection())
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlRequest) as HttpWebRequest;
                request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "my token here";

                using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

                        string line = string.Empty;
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            sb.Append(line);
                        }

                        T deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(sb.ToString());

                        return deserializedObject;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("My custom Exception", ex.InnerException);
        }
```

I've looked everywhere whitout any luck. Could someone provide me a further and detailed explanation, or point me out some documents to have a look??

Comment: Both `INTERNET` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are enabled by default in `Debug` configurations. You must explicitly specify these in a `Release` configuration. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml/#Permissions | Can you give us more detail on the issue of accessing internet from your app? What code are you using to access the internet?

Comment: @JonDouglas Yes I'm aware of that. That's why I added those settings to the manifest. I'll post details as how I'm accessing internet shortly, even though it's working fine in debug mode, so I guess that should be fine.

Comment: We would need concrete evidence to help diagnose this issue. When you install your app from `Debug` or Google Play, please go to Settings -> Apps -> Select your App -> Permissions. Screenshots or Text of the exact privileges displayed would help!

Comment: @JonDouglas I've edited my question

Comment: Did you see the same privileges from a complete uninstall of the app and trying both `Debug` and from Google Play? See if the `Debug` build fails with a different linking option other than `Don't Link`.

Comment: @JonDouglas Permissions from Debug or Google Play are the same. Tried building with Sdk and User Assemblies Linking option and it did with no error.... BUT there's no internet in my app!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124818/discussion-between-jon-douglas-and-fabricio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely running into an issue with the `Linker` stripping away something that your application needs. I would highly recommend that you review our documentation on this topic here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#Linker_Behavior

You can then attempt to use `linkskip` (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#linkskip) or a custom linker configuration file(https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/) to ensure your assemblies are included in your final package.

Comment: It was indeed a problem with the linker. Switching to Sdk Assemblies Only did the trick. Either way, I'm gonna check the links provided to avoid having some left out. Thank you very much!