# No internet access in Release mode Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I have develop an LOB app that will be distributed in our own site only to our employees. It uses Webservices to collect data from our sqlserver. In Debug mode works like a charm but when I switch to Release mode for deployment, the app do not have Access to Internet. I include the Internet permission both in manifest and runtime, I even include a routine to ask for the permission if the app detect that such permission is missing, but It never ask to allow for this option. I am deploying to devices with api 23 and above. Could somebody help me?

I also did all that DHLopez. This is the error:

10-02 17:12:07.153 D/libc-netbsd( 7215): [getaddrinfo]: hostname=verut.db.8473427.hostedresource.com; servname=0; netid=0; mark=0
10-02 17:12:07.153 D/libc-netbsd( 7215): [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=2; ai_family=0
10-02 17:12:07.663 D/libc-netbsd( 7215): getaddrinfo: verut.db.8473427.hostedresource.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0

Again, this only happened in Release Mode.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835726/xamarin-android-internet-permission

Comment: Thanks DH It help. I can run in release mode.